# how to create rss feed for a website?

Tags: asp.net

I developed a webapplication,Now i want to create Rss feeds for my website.
In my application i have a module call Film news, which contain the latest news of the film stars. Now i want to create rss feeds for that module. the news contains title and description. How can i create rss feeds for my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code i use for my feed, It's just an .ashx (Generic handler), which I point my website at.

Remember to add this little piece of html to your site:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="/rss.ashx" title="Rss feed for yourdomain.com" />
```

And here's the complete handler code:

```
public class rssHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var Response = context.Response;

        // Prepare response
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/rss+xml";
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10));
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);

        // Create an XmlWriter to write the feed into it
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Response.OutputStream))
        {
            // Set the feed properties
            SyndicationFeed feed = new SyndicationFeed
                ("yourdomain.com",
                "Some description of your feed",
                new Uri("http://www.yourdomain.com"));

            // Add authors
            feed.Authors.Add(new SyndicationPerson
                ("yourmail@yourdomain.com",
                "your name",
                "http://www.yourdomain.com"));

            // Add categories
            NewsType[] categories = (NewsType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(NewsType)); // NewsType is a enum I use, which is custom created

            foreach (var category in categories)
            {
                feed.Categories.Add(new SyndicationCategory(category.GetDescription()));
            }

            // Set copyright
            feed.Copyright = new TextSyndicationContent
                ("© Copyright 2009 your name");

            // Set generator
            feed.Generator = "yourdomain.com";

            // Set language
            feed.Language = "da-DK";

            // Add post items
            List<SyndicationItem> items = new List<SyndicationItem>();
            var newsList = News.GetLatest(20);
            foreach (var news in newsList)
            {
                string url = GetShowUrl(news);
                SyndicationItem item = new SyndicationItem();
                item.Id = news.ID.ToString();
                item.Title = TextSyndicationContent.CreatePlaintextContent(news.Name);
                item.Content = SyndicationContent.CreateXhtmlContent(news.Content);
                item.PublishDate = news.DateCreated.Value;
                item.Categories.Add(new SyndicationCategory(news.NewsType.Value.GetDescription()));
                item.Links.Add(new SyndicationLink(new Uri(url), "alternate", news.Name, "text/html", 1000));
                items.Add(item);
            }
            feed.Items = items;

            // Write the feed to output
            Rss20FeedFormatter formatter = new Rss20FeedFormatter(feed);
            formatter.WriteTo(writer);

            writer.Flush();
        }
        Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string GetShowUrl(News news)
    {
        // Returns proper absolute URL to the item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you should learn the format of a typical RSS feed, heres an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Example Channel</title>
    <link>http://example.com/</link>
    <description>My example channel</description>
    <item>
       <title>News for September the Second</title>
       <link>http://example.com/2002/09/01</link>
       <description>other things happened today</description>
    </item>
    <item>
       <title>News for September the First</title>
       <link>http://example.com/2002/09/02</link>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Next, create a script that queries your database for all the pages you want to include, then output them in a loop so:

```
//begin loop

<item>
   <title>[title]</title>
   <link>[link]</link>
   <description>[description]</description>
</item>

//end loop
```

Once you have this, save the output from your script as feed.rss and place it at the root of your webserver.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

[RSS Reader using ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/xml/rss-aspnet2-vb.aspx)

[How to create your own RSS Reader - .net RSS (C#/VB.NET)](http://cstruter.com/articles/article/2/6)