# Can an rss feed be created for every web page?

Tags: xml, rss, feed

I wish to develop a web app for creating an rss feed for webpages, like http://www.thebetterindia.com/topics/innovation/
which don't currently give the option for subscribing to them via rss.

I want to know about the **various prerequisites for a website/webpage to provide content via rss feeds**.

Also, being new to web development, what technologies and tools are used to create an rss feed for a web page? I searched for it on google, but didn't come across a page explaining how to create rss feed for an *existing* web page, though many gave the details of creating an rss xml file *in general*.

My preferable language is Java.

PS: I found similar questions on stackoverflow, like 
[How to programmatically turn any webpage into an RSS feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4795605/4515198) and [how to create rss feed for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2839102/4515198), but they don't address the question of what properties does a web page need to have to provide content via rss feeds.

Comment: Not sure you can actually create an rss xml file for a *non-existing* webpage??

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier My question is targeted towards web pages which _do exist_, but do not provide the option to subscribe via rss feeds.

Answer (score 0):

RSS is provided by the Web server on which the site is hosted. It's server-side response just xml instead of html. There is not much you can do unless you are the site maintainer to create a RSS feed.

Source Wikipedia